# What is 'this' in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to know that why we use `$(this)` in jQuery. And what is `$(this)`?

```
var color = $(".selected").css("background-color");

$(".controls li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    color = $(this).css("background-color");
});
```

In this code what "this" mean and what is the other option of using 'this'?

Comment: here `$(this)` refers to your `li` element which is nested inside `.controls`

Comment: `this` is what the method was invoked for

Comment: Refers to specific li element was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside a function represents the context in which the function invoked on, if a method is invoked without a context it will be the window object(or undefined in strict mode).

In jQuery event handlers `this` represents the dom element reference on which the handler is registered on so in your case `this` refers to the `li` element. in case of event delegation `this` will refer to the actual target of the handler like if an `li` was targeted by the handler(`$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){...})`) then `this` will be the `li` element

Another option instead of using `this` will be the [currentTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) property of the event object

```
$(".controls li").click(function (e) {
    // or $(e.currentTarget)
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    color = $(this).css("background-color");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h3z284jy/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is the current object.

In the above code - $(this) imeans - `$(".controls li")` (the `li` in `.controls`) from which the event triggered.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is referred as current object. In your case you are triggering click action on `<li>` item in `controls` class selector. So this will be `<li>` in css class `controls`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this)
```

is the object from which the event triggered or the current object the process is handling.